# Sublime Text snippet doesn't work with IIFE

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

This code snippet I added to Sublime Text 3 does not work on the tab trigger unless I remove the **iife**.

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="$1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>${2:Untitled}</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <script>
            // iife
            (function($, window, document) {
                $3
            })(jQuery, window, document);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>doctype</tabTrigger>
    <description>HTML - HTML foundation</description>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: What `iife`? I don't see those letters in conjunction anywhere in your snippet...

Comment: The content of the script tags.

Comment: @MattDMo IIFE are [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/) it's a common pattern in JavaScript world.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add a backslash to the dollar sign:

```
(function(\$, window, document) {
    $3
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Sorry for the confusion about the iife:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression